# Combining data with numpy across two files

Tags: python, numpy

In my problem there are two files, which I would like to combine into a dataset two files. The first file has an implicit line number which is referenced in the second file as ident. So Janine is ident 1, jasmine is ident 2, judith is ident 3.

Names:

```
Name    Address
Janine  Unicorn Lane
Jasmine Sparkles Street
Judith  Rainbow Avenue
```

Telephone Numbers:

```
Number Ident
123    1
893    1
345    2 
746    3
```

How do I combine these two tables to get for each Address the Telephone Number? What I would like to do is something like :

```
data[Adress='Unicorn Lane']['Number'].mean()
```

ok, this example is probably not good. But illustrates what I need.

Comment: Please explain, how the two files are connected. Is `Ident` the line number from the first file?

Comment: Sounds like you want an RDBMS, though maybe [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) will cut it for you.

Comment: thez are connected via ident and the order of the first file. i include an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably manage something with structured arrays:

- Create two structured arrays `names` and `numbers` from your two files, using `np.genfromtxt` for example. Don't forget to use `dtype=None` (let `np.genfromtxt` guess your data types) and `names=True` (field names should be read from the first column), probably with `delimiter="\t"`.

Your `names` will have something like `dtype([('Name', '|S7'), ('Adress', '|S16')])`, your `numbers` something like `dtype([('Number', '<i8'), ('Ident', '<i8')])`.

Afterwards, it's just a matter of fancy indexing to get your selection. For example, if you want the indices of the entries of `names` for `"Unicorn Lane"`:

```
    (idx,) = np.nonzero(names['Adress']=="Unicorn Lane")
```

(the `np.nonzero` should return a tuple with one element, an array of indices). With your example, `idx = array([0])`...)

You can use those indices as identifiers, keeping in mind that they start at 0 when your identifiers start at 1. So, to select the `numbers` for which the `Ident` matches the indices you had found:

```
numbers[numbers['Ident'] == idx+1]
```

(remember, in our example, `idx=array([0])` corresponds to `Ident==1`...).

You should check that `idx` is not empty (`idx.size >0`). Otherwise `idx+1` will be empty too, `numbers['Ident']==idx+1` will evaluate to `False`, and in NumPy, `numbers[False]` is equivalent to `numbers[0]`.

Comment: can you help me once again? print numbers[numbers['ident'] == idx[0]+1] works and gives me all records belonging to idx[0], but numbers[numbers['ident'] == idx+1] just gives me the first record. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `idx` in your second problem (`numbers[numbers['ident'] == idx+1]`) ?